# How do I stop my headlights from turning on automatically when my key is in the on position?

Tags: nissan

My 2004 Nissan pulsar headlights turn on automatically when my key is turned to the ON position. The headlights stay on while I’m driving but I don’t want them to be on. Please help me get this fixed.

Comment: It does not need fixing. It is there to « help » those who are not smart enough to remember to turn their headlights on when they need to be. Actually saw two like that last night...

Comment: This is called daytime running lights and they are the law in some places, you should find out if you are legally required to have them before you turn them off.

Comment: Solar Mike, I see people running around at night with no lights on, apparently because "they're too cool" to turn the lights on and want to be different. I can tell because of getting cussed out when I tell them about it. It's the inverse of those types who run the fog lights on a perfectly clear night.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the DRL module and pull its connector right out. Alternatively, you may play with the fuse marked 10 or 21, but this may disable other stuff as well.

Here's the wiring diagram, which I assumed to be from the right vehicle:

[image]